# ri returns no information about class "GC"

Tags: ruby

Just did a new install of ruby onto an ubuntu server using the rvm method. `ruby -v` returns my version I am running, `1.9.2` just fine and I am able to execute the basic code I am doing from a book I am trying to learn from. 
So at the command promp, the following

```
ri GC
```

returns

```
Nothing known about GC
```

where the expected result is something like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------- Class: GC
The GC module provides an interface to Ruby's mark and sweep
garbage collection mechanism. Some of the underlying methods are 
also available via the ObjectSpace module.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

At first I thought it might relate to not having a gems dealt with yet, but I downloaded the `1.6.2` tar and ran the setup.rb with no issues.

One other note, I have attempted to install other version of ruby using methods that I later discovered were wretched indeed and have since cleaned them up to my knowledge. Not inclined to have to start from scratch on this dev box especially if this has a quick fix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm docs generate
```

By default, RVM does not generate docs for the rubies you install.

See [RVM docs -> Rubies -> Docs](https://rvm.io/rubies/docs)

Answer (score 2):

Does this:

> `ri --system --site --home --gems GC`

Fix it?

If not, try running:

> `ri --classes | grep GC`

And check that you have a line like this one:

> `FloatDomainError, Foo, Forwardable,`
>   `GC, GServer, Gem, Gem::Builder,`

Comment: Also I'd like to mention that having `ri` broken is not a big deal

Comment: and got the same as before.  the ri --classes | grep GC  returns nothing either as since ri --classes returns the --help as well as "invalid option"

Comment: I did do a fresh vm of ubuntu 10.10 in the meantime and got the same issue as on the old ubuntu server vm, so we can rule out at least the junk I did on it prior to this install.  I am running all of the new solution on both systems in case there is some confusion.  again, thanks for your help in advance

Comment: im not too worried about not having the documentation working, but I am concerned that the install may be incomplete or corrupted and will bite me in the arse in the furture.

Comment: Can you try using `rvm` and a different ruby vm? Perhaps jruby or rubinius?